# CompizConfig-style Tiling in GNOME

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz

While using the Unity desktop under 17.04 I used CompizConfig to allow window tiling with keyboard shortcuts.

The feature I most liked and relied on was the ability to tile windows to the 4 corners, left or right, top or bottom with keyboard shortcuts (I adjust mine to be ctrl + super + [1 - 9]) where each of the numbers placed a window in a tile position similar to the placement of the number on a 3 x 3 number pad.

So, ctrl + super + 1 would place a window in the bottom left corner, ctrl + super + 8 would place a window on the top half of the screen, ctrl + super + 6 would place a window on the right half of the screen, etc.

Is there a way to get this functionality in GNOME? Either through using CompizConfig somehow or by using another GNOME extension?

Comment: Mind checking [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/) ? Also searching in Google actually return many result https://www.google.com/search?q=gnome+tile+window

Comment: @Sans Thanks for the suggestion, I tried gTile and had an error message telling me that it failed to run. I'll try again tomorrow and create a new question if I need help getting it started.